# Excel - Separate Comma List Into Cells Using a Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1. I have a list of values: *shoes, hats, umbrellas, towels, disks*
2. Need to separate list values into **three** different cells using a formula.

For example:

```
+-------+------+-----------+
| shoes | hats | umbrellas |
+-------+------+-----------+
```

I could use a different formula in each cell to accomplish this. Whatever the case, I need this to be done using a formula. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Use Text-to-Columns and on the third screen, select columns 4 and choose Do not import column (skip). Repeat for column 5 and click Finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *shoes, hats, umbrellas, towels, disks* in A2, put this into a column to the right.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2, ",",  REPT(" ", 999)), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1, 999))
```

Fill right for a total of three columns then fill down as necessary.

[image: Split CSV to three columns]

Comment: I have to plugin this into a huge excel sheet, mind explaining how it works so I can translate it into my sheet? Thank you very much!